# How do I resolve this error I am getting in pom.xml file after installing a Spring Book Project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, frameworks

I created a Spring Boot Project from the Spring Boot Initializr Website and once I imported this project as a Maven, I keep getting an error on the pom.xml file and my code is not compiling.
I'm not sure why I'm getting this error even after trying to google the resolutions. I also tried t o modify the pom.xml file and I noticed that the moment I added a 'parent' tag in the file, I get this error. Does someone know why this is happening?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Sd2.png)

Comment: provide the whole pom.xml

Comment: put the code instead of an image.

Comment: When I entered the actual code from the xml file, its not pasting the entire file here. So i had to copy another screenshot. The Hyperlink contains the full code picture.

Comment: Below is the xml code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
</project>

Comment: It looks like the pom file is corrupted. That could be due to a temporary glitch or a network configuration problem. To rule out a glitch, try deleting the file mentioned in the error message and then `Maven -> Update Project…` in Eclipse.

Comment: Please, no pictures of POM files...

Answer (score 0):

I think relative path is the problem. Try removing it, check out this https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-boot-starter-parent-dependency/